How do I set a default end screen for YouTube videos?
I am posting videos to my YouTube channel and want to have a standard end screen for each video. Currently, while YouTube does allow me to import end screens from previous videos, I need to import the end screen for every upload individually.
How do I either set a default end screen or set the end screen for multiple videos at once?

